# MySQL transactions with schema modification statements (DDL)?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, database-schema, ddl

Despite commit or rollback, the change is "commited" in both cases.

Commit:

```
START TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE `bank` CHANGE COLUMN `bank_active` `bank_activated` BOOLEAN NOT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Rollback:

```
START TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE `bank` CHANGE COLUMN `bank_active` `bank_activated` BOOLEAN NOT NULL;
ROLLBACK;
```

Need to build an automatic updater, that includes database's schema and data updates, and would like to group everything into a transaction, so in case anything goes wrong, just fix the statements and run again.

Is it possible to rollback DDL statements within transactions?

Thank you

Comment: FWIW this works in PostgreSQL. This can be good to know when picking what database to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BEGIN` in some contexts is the same as `START TRANSACTION`.

phpmyadmin performs one query at a time unless you put the batch in the window for such.  Try that.

(And `SET autocommit = 0` is irrelevant because of the explicit `START`.)

**Edit**

Since the "transaction" really had a DDL statement, my 'answer' is irrelevant.

DDLs cannot be rolled back: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html